# Dynamically adding/removing rows in a table using jQuery/Javascript

Tags: jquery, html-table

I had gone through many solutions for the above problem but they are quite confusing as I 'cell left & cell right' didn't seem to be applicable in my case.

Using clone method of jQuery is quite simpler, but there is also one problem. The problem is that when I clone the last row it will copy all data from above row. another problem attached to it is : ID. When cloning is done, same 'name' & 'ID' is copied which will create problem while posting data, so I need dynamics in this too. So I m not getting that how can we pass data to clone function which will solve dynamic 'attribute' problem.

CODE:

```
<table id="advertisement_main_table" class="table" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1" width="100%;">  
<tr class="odd align_center">
                    <td>1.</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="ad_elements" class="textbox_150_with_border"></td>
                    <td><textarea id="ad_description" rows="01" cols="50" class="advertisement_textarea" ></textarea></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="ad_duration" class="textbox_60_with_border"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="ad_loop_day" class="textbox_60_with_border"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="ad_seconds_played" class="textbox_100_with_border"></td>
                </tr></table>
```

Now in above code `<td>1.</td>` is hardcoded but how to appended 'suffix' in every id like 'ad_element_1','ad_duration_1',,,'ad_element_2','ad_duration_2' in next `<tr>` and so on..

I hope you understand what I want to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the solution is to use `<input type="text" name="ad_elements[]" class="textbox_150_with_border" />` instead of an id there. That way when it's cloned the name is still valid, and you'll just receive an array of ad_elements entries when it's posted.

For the rest, like turning the "1." into "2.", I'm afraid there is no magic bullet, you've to do that yourself after the cloning, it's fairly easy in this particular case though:

$(new_tr).find('td:first-child').text(function(text) {
       return (parseInt(text)+1) + ".";
   });

Just replace new_tr by whatever variable contains the cloned TR.

Comment: it seem to me that u didnt understand what i was trying to say.ur name='xyz[]' solution is helpful but i need to set every attribute when generating row, passing value through clone function,if possible.According to ur solution, i wil edit data in first td and similarly i had to clear every input box. So i want a solution that i dont need to clear data when new row gets created.

Comment: Then your only way is to use a row template somewhere else that will never be altered by the user, and that one you can clone at will without needing to reset anything. You could use a hidden <tr> somewhere for this purpose, or better store it in a `<script id="row-tpl" type="text/template"><tr>...etc...</tr></script>`. You can then read that script's content from javascript using $('#row-tpl').text()` and append that to your table. The `type="text/template"` will prevent the browser from executing it as javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery template plugin to achieve this. Create a markup to add rows of the table and iterate it within a template. Then call the function on page load or OnClick of any button or wherever you need it. If you need any server side data, that also could be done by creating a web method and returning a jason object. You can find more info at: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/

Answer (score 0):

Well if your adding dynamic elements, chances are ids aren't really needed here anyway; there probably isn't any CSS or jQuery selectors specfically associated with the new ids, afterall, they *don't exist* until they are created, if at all, so you could simply remove them:

```
$(clonedRow).find('*').removeAttr('id');
```

Otherwise if you really want new ids, you could just keep a global counter `newId` and associate new ids for each element:

```
newId++;
$(clonedRow).find('*').attr('id', function() {
  if (this.id.length) return this.id + '_' + newId;
});
```

[**See here as fiddle demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/jd9aS/2/) *hover over the input elements to see new id*

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this problem.

```
var $newRow = $("#tableName tbody>tr:last").clone();
$newRow.find('input').attr('someAttribute','0');
$newRow.find('input').attr('anotherAttribute','1');
$('#tableName>tbody').append($newRow);
```

Just replace 'input' with the type of control you have in your table. And 'someAttribute' with the actual attribute name, the second argument is of course your value to that attribute.